# Projects containing version 2.4 deployment descriptors require XMI-format bindings or extensions files.ibm-web-ext.xml

Tags: xmi

I just migrated a project from java 1.5 to 1.6 using IBM-RAD and i am getting this error

Projects containing version 2.4 deployment descriptors require XMI-format bindings or extensions files.ibm-web-ext.xml

Solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change version of servlet from 2.4 to > 2.5 and tried? it works for me